# What does the following bash program call do?

Tags: c, bash, command-line-arguments, stdout, stdin

I am going through my revision material and can't understand the following:

I have a compiled C `myCProgram` program which prints out its input in the form of text. So if it were called in bash by
`./myCProgram input.txt` and `input.txt` contained `"this is a test"` the program would output on stdout `"this is a test"`. I have a range of potential bash program calls to test and I pass all but one, it is of the following

```
./myCProgram file.txt < input.txt
```

It is is decribed as: Your program takes a file as a single command line argument and then expect input on stdin.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here and suggest how I should handle it within my code?

Comment: Read more about *redirection*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirects the content of input.txt to your program via stdin. This does the same as:

```
./myCProgram file.txt
```

and then typing in the contents of input.txt